# Android AlertDialog with AppCompat style - background issue

Tags: android, xamarin, android-appcompat

Based on few websites, I applied AppCompat theme to AlertDialog.
One issue appeared:

[image]

How can I remove these gray gaps ?

My style for this AlertDialog:

```
<style name="MyTheme.Dark.Dialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
   <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
   <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/primary</item>
   <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
   <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/iron</item>
   <item name="android:background">@color/primary</item>
   <item name="android:buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/customButtonStyle</item>
   <item name="android:fullDark">@color/red</item>
   <item name="android:topDark">@color/red</item>
   <item name="android:centerDark">@color/red</item>
   <item name="android:bottomDark">@color/red</item>
   <item name="android:fullBright">@color/red</item>
   <item name="android:topBright">@color/red</item>
   <item name="android:centerBright">@color/red</item>
   <item name="android:bottomBright">@color/red</item>
   <item name="android:bottomMedium">@color/red</item>
   <item name="android:centerMedium">@color/red</item>
</style>

<style name="customButtonStyle" >
   <item name="android:textColor">@color/iron</item>
   <item name="android:background">@color/primary</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Show me some code...May be issue with wrong import, confirm that you are using the AlertDialog class from android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog and not from android.app.AlertDialog. Hope this helps

Comment: You are right. The problem was related with wrong namespace for AlertDialog. Thanks!

Comment: please add this as answer. I had this problem and searched for hours. Trying every possible combination in styles...

Comment: @darwin Please, provide your comment as an answer than I will mark it as right answer

Comment: Added my comment as answer,hope this helps others also.thank you for your feedback and suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If u are using Appcompact as your app theme,then make sure that AlertDialog is imported from the Appcompact support library.

Confirm that you are using the AlertDialog class from android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog and not from android.app.AlertDialog.